# Hugo site isn't starting locally

Tags: github-pages, hugo

I'm currently trying to build a Hugo site locally, and no content is showing. I'd love more trouble-shooting steps or anything that can help me do a clean rebuild so I don't have to transfer all my posts over to a Google site.

I've tried re-instantiating the site, rebuilding it with `hugo`, starting the server with `hugo server` and `hugo server -D`, but I'm only getting a blank screen.

I have pages that aren't drafts, so something should definitely be showing. It's possible the public or index folder are goofed, but I'm not sure.

`hugo version`: `Hugo Static Site Generator v0.48/extended darwin/amd64`

`go version`: `go version go1.11.2 darwin/amd64`

`config.toml`:

```
baseURL = ""
languageCode = "en-us"
title = ""
theme = "ananke"

[menu]

  [[menu.main]]
    identifier = "Posts"
    name = "Posts"
    pre = "<i class='fa fa-road'></i>"
    url = "/posts/"
    weight = -100

[params]

    featured_image = "images/space-cat-wallpaper.jpg"
    twitter = ""
```

When building the pages with `hugo`:

```
                   | EN  
+------------------+----+
  Pages            | 72  
  Paginator pages  |  0  
  Non-page files   |  0  
  Static files     | 21  
  Processed images |  0  
  Aliases          |  1  
  Sitemaps         |  1  
  Cleaned          |  0  

Total in 88 ms
```

When starting the local instance with `hugo server -D`:

```
                   | EN   
+------------------+-----+
  Pages            | 117  
  Paginator pages  |   5  
  Non-page files   |   0  
  Static files     |  21  
  Processed images |   0  
  Aliases          |   1  
  Sitemaps         |   1  
  Cleaned          |   0  

Total in 120 ms
Watching for changes in /Users/jschalz/Desktop/hugo-jschalz.github.io-2/{content,data,layouts,static,themes}
Watching for config changes in /Users/jschalz/Desktop/hugo-jschalz.github.io-2/config.toml
Serving pages from memory
Running in Fast Render Mode. For full rebuilds on change: hugo server --disableFastRender
Web Server is available at http://localhost:1313/ (bind address 127.0.0.1)
Press Ctrl+C to stop
```

After running `hugo -v --debug -D` I get the following warnings and then a LOT of debug noise:

```
WARN 2019/06/16 16:33:21 No translation bundle found for default language "en"
WARN 2019/06/16 16:33:21 Translation func for language en not found, use default.
WARN 2019/06/16 16:33:21 i18n not initialized, check that you have language file (in i18n) that matches the site language or the default language.
```

Navigating to localhost:1313 gives me a blank screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `hugo -v --debug -D` could tell you more

Second, to be really sure something is generated, try:

```
hugo server --renderToDisk --gc --cleanDestinationDir
```

Check that files are created (as opposed to be served in memory)

Note: I always prefer adding in my `config.toml`

```
builddrafts = true
```

It is useful when starting a project, to be sure *everything* is generated.

The [OP ladygremlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11646003/ladygremlin)  confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56622740/hugo-site-isnt-starting-locally/56622776?noredirect=1#comment99818614_56622776):

> I think the `builddrafts = true` in the `config.toml` fixed it!
>   I also upgraded to the newest version of hugo.

Comment: I tried `hugo -v --debug -D` and got a couple warnings I'll add to the original post. The second command still didn't produce any pages, but also didn't state they were served in memory, which is probably better. :)

Comment: @ladygremlin as long as no pages are generated on disk... that would be a problem indeed.

Comment: @ladygremlin Beside the warnings, you do have md files in content, as in https://github.com/alex-shpak/hugo-book/issues/23#issuecomment-465482608?

Comment: @ladygremlin Does your local path folder has any special character? (as in https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/3726)

Comment: I think the `builddrafts = true` in the `config.toml` fixed it! I also upgraded to the newest version of hugo. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have any special characters in my path, but that's good to know for the future. :)

Comment: @ladygremlin Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thank you! I'll be more careful in the future!